# How do I find out my Maven deploy directory?

Tags: maven, deployment

I have my source code in Git and use Maven to deploy it to an Archiva repo.

I somehow don't exactly know where my deploy directory is. I would like to copy a kar file there so that it can be deployed when Jenkins builds it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: so that i can copy my kar files there so that maven can deploy them since it can't deploy them otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

your deploy directory is groupId/artifactId/version depending in wich repository you deployed (SNAPSHOT,release, or thirdpary), generally you should build in a different project your kar file and then use as a dependency in the other project. 
You shoud not copy any files in a repository without a pom.xml.
Or you can just deploy with deploy:file

Comment: There do actually exist means by which you can build and deploy a kar file but it just needs to be copied to that directory from which maven will take all the built artifacts and deploy them to my repo. So I just need to be able to find that directory in my project because normally it's the target dir created by maven but in such a big project I'm struggling to find it... Maybe it's not persistent after a build?

Comment: can you be a bit more concrete, i am not sure to understand what you mean. 
What I am understanding: you have a file (kar) and you want to use in a maven project in one of your directory ? is this correct?